# Dynamic Routing with two Dashes in path AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an interesting problem, I have this rule for routing

`"/upload_image/:lat-:lng"` , where `lat` and `lng` are geo-coordinates.

When I try to access with a path like this `/upload_image/42.04648822804604--71.65695190429688` where the first dash is the separator between `lat` and `lng` as defined in the rule above.

But what happens actually when I try to access `$routeParams` with
`lat` = `42.04648822804604-` and `lng` = `71.65695190429688`, which are false coordinates, angularjs took the second dash as separator between two parameters according to the rule above,

Any solution to make it pick up the first dash always? ( I know I can use other separator than dash but interested to know if there is a solution + dash is nicer although).

**Update:**
This is the result of interesting discussion on #angularjs channel on freenode (from the docs it looks like that's not supposed to work. the ":" is supposed to take up everything till the next slash (or literal I guess) so it's a greedy match. [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$routeProvider](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24routeProvider))